# AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService used by default by Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

If i did not misunderstand, `AuthenticationProvider` uses `UserDetailsService` to retreive a user's attributes in order to authenticate an `Authentication` object.

Problem is that in the next code there is no configuration for an `AuthenticationProvider` neither for a `UserDetailsService`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("ADMIN").and().withUser("user1")
            .password("pass").roles("USER");
}
```

Yet the authentication service has been set.

My question is, was there an implementation for `AuthenticationProvider` and another one for `UserDetailsService` that were added to the spring context internally? In this case, what are the used implementations (in the case of memoryAuthentication).

Does the `*.withUser("user").password("pass").roles("ADMIN")*` part of the configuration represent a `UserDetailsService` implementation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for such a configuration `AuthenticationProvider` and `UserDetailsService` beans are configured implicitly.

`.inMemoryAuthentication()` configures Spring Security to use `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` which (indirectly) implements `UserDetailsService` interface, so it is a `UserDetailsService` itself.

`DaoAuthenticationProvider` is used as `AuthenticationProvider` implementation by default with `inMemoryAuthentication()`.

`.withUser("user").password("pass").roles("ADMIN")` configures user known to `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`. This can be used to populate it with users you'd like to use for logging in.

One more thing: not all `AuthenticationProvider`s use `UserDetailsService` to obtain user details. Actually, among the standard `AuthenticationProvider` implementations, only `DaoAuthenticationProvider` class uses `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: Did you mean that by default, Spring boot uses DaoAuthenticationProvider and InMemoryUserDetailManager?

Comment: Roman, when a CustomUserDetailsService is used which AuthenticationProvider Implementation is used?